# objective-c two objects allocated have same memory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created 2 objects:

```
NSNumber * index1 = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0 autorelease];
NSNumber * index2 = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0 autorelease];
```

and put a breackpoint after the allocation, but INCREDIBLY i see the same address for the two objects:

[image]

and [index1 isEqual: index2] return always TRUE
??? why?

Comment: looks like a basic optimisation : 2 objects create at same time with same value sharing pointer. if you change value of one of them it will change this memory address too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why NSNumber points to the same address when value are equals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270121/why-nsnumber-points-to-the-same-address-when-value-are-equals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an internal optimisation.  NSNumbers are immutable, so, to save space, if you ask for an NSNumber representation of 0 (and some other small constants) you always get back the same object.

Comment: ok, all clear but IMO this is a too much "aggressive" optimization, i need two different objects with the same value, I must create my own obj type?

Comment: You want two different NSNumbers that represent 0?  Why?

Comment: because the both values 0 is a coincidence, generally have different values, after the creation I insert this NSNumbers in an array, and looping this array for (NSNumber * numIndex in searchIndexes) I check: [numIndex isequal index1]

Comment: @Kappe That will still work, you can put the same object in an array more than once.

Comment: sure work, but the comparision always return true because any nsnumber are equal, and if i have the same int the objects I can't distinguish them. UPDATE: i use a fu**ing NSString :D

Comment: If you are trying to differentiate between two values of 0, you're doing it wrong :)  In any case `-isEqual:` would return true for two different NSNumber objects both representing `0` in much the same way as it returns true for two different `NSString`s both representing `@"0"`

Comment: If you need to enforce *pointer identity*, you need to create a subclass of NSObject.  However, this would be a decidedly odd pattern. "This 0 is the same as that 0, but not the same as the other 0 over here."  Ouch.

Comment: @bbum:  that was my thought too.

Answer (score 3):

It is an optimization. NSNumbers are immutable, and an NSNumber with the same int value as another will *always* be the same as the other, so there is no sense in having them be two separate objects. This makes comparing two NSNumbers trivial, because you can use the address to check equivalence instead of comparing internal values.