# iOS - Why Does It Work When I Compare Two NSNumbers With "=="?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compare, nsnumber

In my app, I accidentally used "==" when comparing two `NSNumber` objects like so:

```
NSNumber *number1;
NSNumber *number2;
```

Later on, after these objects' `int` values were set, I accidentally did this:

```
if (number1 == number2) {
    NSLog(@"THEY'RE EQUAL");
}
```

And, confusingly, it worked! I could have sworn I was taught to do it this way:

```
if (number1.intValue == number2.intValue) {
    NSLog(@"THEY'RE EQUAL");
}
```

How did using "==" between the two `NSNumber` objects work, and why? Does that mean it's okay to compare them that way, or was it just a fluke and this is generally not guaranteed to work every time? It really confused me :(

Comment: Actually, the "intValue" will fail in many cases. If both NSNumbers contain large integers, or nearby but different floating point numbers, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is possibly a fluke.

From [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/equality/#equality-&-identity) :

> Two objects may be equal or equivalent to one another, if they share a common set of observable properties. Yet, those two objects may still be thought to be distinct, each with their own identity. In programming, an object’s identity is tied to its memory address.

Its possible that your statement evaluated to `YES` because `number1` and `number2` were pointing to the same object. This would not work if they had the same value but were two different objects.

The obvious reason `NSNumber` variables would point to the same would be that you explicitly assigned one to the other, like so:

```
number1 = number2;
```

But there's one other **thing**. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270158/3894781) :

> This is likely either a compiler optimisation or an implementation detail: as NSNumber is immutable there's no need for them be separate instances. probably an implementation optimisation thinking about it. Likely numberWithInt returns a singleton when called subsequently with the same integer.

But anyways, its safest to use `isEqualToNumber:`, as there is no telling what other "**things**" are lurking in the depths of code that may or may not cause it to evaluate `YES`

From [RyPress](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsnumber#comparing-numbers) :

> While it’s possible to directly compare NSNumber pointers, the isEqualToNumber: method is a much more robust way to check for equality. It guarantees that two values will compare equal, even if they are stored in different objects.

Comment: I read here (http://www.toptal.com/ios/interview-questions) (just control-f search "==" and you'll find the question and answer) that the iOS Compiler is optimized to set the same address in memory for two `NSStrings` that share the same value. Maybe the same works for `NSNumber`?

Comment: Yeah but I don't think that applies to `NSNumber`. I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: Hmmm, so if I have "Friend" objects where each one's `NSNumber` "identifier" attribute will always be assigned and referenced as an `intValue`, I can always get away with comparison using "=="?

Comment: @Rafi Updated my answer. Damn! I didn't know all these things until now. So thanks for the question.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the very well detailed and cited answer!

Comment: `NSNumber`s on recent systems are now "tagged pointers". Instances _are_ indeed reused, and additionally the pointer itself encodes the numeric value. See [Marcio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107023/603977).

Answer (score 10):

It's not a fluke.
It's due to the tagged pointers feature of the Objective-C runtime while using an ARM64 CPU.

> In Mac OS X 10.7, Apple introduced tagged pointers. Tagged pointers allow certain classes with small amounts of per-instance data to be stored entirely within the pointer. This can eliminate the need for memory allocations for many uses of classes like NSNumber, and can make for a good performance boost.[…] on ARM64, the Objective-C runtime includes tagged pointers, with all of the same benefits they've brought to the Mac

[Source](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-09-27-arm64-and-you.html)

Answer (score 2):

There two concepts of equality at work here:

- Object identity: Comparing that two pointers point to the same objects
- Value equality: That the contents of two objects are equal.

In this case, you want value equality.  In your code you declare two pointers to `NSNumber` objects:

```
NSNumber *number1;
NSNumber *number2;
```

But at no point show assignment of a value to them.  This means the contents of the pointers can be anything, and quite by chance you have two pointers pointing to the memory locations (not necessarily the same ones) where `(number1.intValue == number2.intValue)` happens to be true.

You can expect the behaviour to change in unstable ways - for instance as soon as you add any more code.

Comment: Note that under ARC, uninitialized object pointer values **are** well-defined: they are `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can compare two NSNumber* with ==. This will tell you whether the pointers are equal. Of course if the pointers are equal then the values must be the same. The values can be the same without the pointers being equal.

Now you need to be aware that MaxOS X and iOS do some significant optimisations to save storage, especially in 64 bit code. Many NSNumbers representing the same integer value will actually be the same pointer.

```
NSNumber* value1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1];
NSNumber* value2 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1];
```

These will be the *same* pointers. In 64 bit, many others will be the same pointers. There are only ever two NSNumber objects with boolean values. There is only ever one empty NSArray object, and only one [NSNull null] object.

Don't let that lull you into any wrong assumptions. If you want to see if two NSNumbers have the same value, use isEqualToNumber: You may say "if (number1 == number2 || [number1 isEqualToNumber:number2])"; that's fine (didn't check if I got the names right).