# Why do two NSStrings taken from user input end up with the same address?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I am curious to know how the OS or compiler manages the memory usage. Take this example of a login screen.

If I enter the same strings for both user ID & password: say "anoop" both times, the following two strings have same addresses:

```
NSString *userID = self.userNameField.stringValue;
NSString *password = self.passwordField.stringValue;
```

If I enter "anoop" & "Anoop" respectively, the address changes.

How does the compiler know that the the password text is same as the user ID, so that instead of allocating a new memory space it uses the same reference?

Comment: If what you're saying is true, this would not be a function of the compiler or the OS; it would only be a function of the `NSString` class (or of the Cocoa library as a whole perhaps) doing some behind-the-scenes string table management.

Comment: As pretty much always, Mike Ash explains it all: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html Strings that are "short enough" are stored right in the pointer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ah, yes, of course! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in this case is that you are testing on a 64-bit platform with Objective-C tagged pointers. In this system, some "pointers" are not memory addresses at all; they encode data directly in the pointer value instead.

One kind of tagged pointer on these systems encodes short strings of common characters entirely in the pointer, and "anoop" is a string that can be encoded this way.

Check out [Friday Q&A 2015-07-31: Tagged Pointer Strings](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) for a very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35808455/4296447) for an explanation of the exact mechanism for short strings on the 64-bit runtime.

Non-mutable `NSString` instances (well, the concrete immutable subclass instances, as NSString is a class cluster) are uniqued by the `NSString` class under certain conditions. Even copying such a string will just return itself instead of creating an actual copy.

It may seem strange, but works well in practice, as the semantics of immutable strings allow it: the string cannot change, ever, so a copy of it will forever be indistinguishable from the original string.

Some of the benefits are: smaller memory footprint, less cache thrashing, faster string compares (as two constant strings just need their addresses compared to check for equality).

Comment: When receiving `-copy` an instance of `NSString` *knows*, that a copy is meaningless. If it is user input, uniquing strings would require a look-up to all existing instances of `NSString`. This is a big difference.

Comment: IIRC, it is a similar thing as is done with [NSNumber](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270121/why-nsnumber-points-to-the-same-address-when-value-are-equals).

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad PS: `NSString` does a lot of magic, and I am not entirely sure how and when exactly it's done, but it could be as simple as caching N recent string allocations with their hashes. It is not needed to keep track of ALL string instances for this to work.

Comment: Of course, you can only do some magic of some "highlights". My point is that you cannot compare it to `-copy`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to know, how you checked that. ;-)

However, a user input is done, when the program is executed. At this point in time there is no compiler anymore. So the compiler cannot do any optimization (string matching).

But your Q is broader than your example. And the answer is as in many programming language: If the memory usage is known at compile time ("static", "stack allocated") the compiler generates code that reserves the memory on stack. This applies to local vars.

If the memory usage is not known at compile time, for example if memory is allocated explicitly by the program, the code tells the system to reserve the amount of memory.

Comment: Yes, I checked that. I never thought this would really happen. I never checked in my 6+ yrs of Obj-C! But today while debugging I printed both value and got shocked both address were same. I re-run the app, with and without breakpoints, printed the addresses....same result.

Comment: For string literals this is documented and it is documented, too, that you cannot rely on it.