# NSDistributedNotification on macOS intermittently doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, nsnotification, nsdistributednotification

I am using NSDistributedNotifications as an IPC on macOS between two processes. Sometimes I see that the notification is sent but is not received and the desired operation is not executed.

Sender Code:

`[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"doSomething" object:myObject userInfo:config deliverImmediately:YES];`

Receiver's code:

`[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(myfunc:) name:@"doSomething" object:myObject];`

Is there a way to debug this? Can I run some command line utility like dtrace or so to see if the notification was even sent to the desired process? Any help will be appreciable

Comment: Where does the receiver's `myObject` come from?

Comment: it is a common string between sender and receiver that I use to uniquely identify the sender.

Comment: Is it the same object (same address)?

Comment: It is a string and the sender and receiver dont share the same object. Think of it as a key that identifies the sender which essentially defines "I am interested in notifications only sent by the process with the key". If I set it to `nil`, the process will receive all distributed notifications.

Comment: You're observing the notificiations sent by the receiver's `myObject`.

Comment: Yes .. sender's object = receiver's object

Comment: No, sender's object is equal to receiver's object. They aren't the same object.

Comment: They don't have the same address in memory. But they do have the same string value which I have denoted by "myObject". Note that I do receive notifications 75% of the time but for some unknown reasons, I don't receive it at random time.

Comment: Maybe this question explains why it works: [Why do two NSStrings taken from user input end up with the same address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801842/why-do-two-nsstrings-taken-from-user-input-end-up-with-the-same-address/35808455#35808455)

Comment: I get your point but I think whatever I have read on [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Communication.html)  says different.  `When using distributed notifications, though, the object must be a string (CFString or NSString). A useful choice for the observed string is the bundle identifier of the target application.`  Can you confirm if the object should really have the same address?

Comment: I didn't read the whole story, only the documentation of `addObserver`. What you're saying makes more sense.